# Taking yearly data, making it monthly, and interpolating

Tags: interpolation, stata

My team and I are trying to use Stata on a yearly dataset we have. We need to make this data monthly and fill in the gaps.

```
  data1 data2 data3 data4
  year1 year1 year1 year1
  year2 year2 year2 year2
```

etc etc

I know that there are questions similar to this one, but I've been unable to find something that deals with annual to monthly.

Comment: I'm not sure what your data look like but you could see `help expand` and that may be useful.

Comment: Following up on Eric's comment, you will improve your chances of an answer if you review the advice at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. As stated, it's not clear if your annual data are to be copied to 12 months (as `expand` would do), divided among 12 months, smoothly interpolated across 12 months (as `ipolate` would do), or something else altogether.

Comment: I didn't downvote. I limited myself to the homily below.

Answer (score 0):

As already commented, this question is vague on several crucial details and below forum standards in not giving a data example that can be used or showing any attempt at code!

The following example points up some of several decisions that need to be made and is not (cannot be) a complete tutorial.

As sandbox we use the Grunfeld data and keep the first panel only. That gives us 20 annual observations. Extension of the method here to multiple panel data is not difficult.

```
webuse grunfeld, clear
keep if company == 1
```

We're going to assign yearly values to July. Other choices are clearly possible. So, we are going to need to interpolate values for the 11 other months. One way to get monthly data is to add 11 observations, populate those with values for the months 1 to 6 and 8 to 12.

```
gen month = 7
set obs 31
replace month = _n - 20 in 21/26
replace month = _n - 19 in 27/31
```

We can get all the (month, year) combinations using `fillin` except that goes a little further than we want. A side-effect of the `set obs` command is missing values on `year` in some observations.

```
fillin month year
drop if missing(year)
```

Now we need a monthly date variable.

```
gen mdate = ym(year, month)
format mdate %tm
```

Now comes the interpolation and there are several ways to do it. One command with various methods is `mipolate` which must be installed from SSC before you can use it. Arbitrarily we choose `pchip`. A graph is not shown here but should be considered essential as a check that you got sensible results. A small but possibly helpful detail is that plotting interpolated with an open symbol and actual with a plus makes it obvious which is which.

```
* the command below need only be issued once 
ssc inst mipolate 
mipolate mvalue mdate, gen(mvalue2) pchip
scatter mvalue2 mvalue mdate, ms(Oh +)
```

In other problems (perhaps most) there is a monthly dataset and a yearly dataset which you `merge` before interpolating. It remains crucial to interpolate on the monthly date variable. If you want a command that takes values, looks at a yearly date variable, and then interpolates on the monthly date variable, you can have that, but you'll need to write it yourself!

A separate interpolation is needed for each outcome of interest.

Although it should be obvious, note that nothing here imputes a seasonal cycle, either on average or for individual years. Economists who seem to want this most often usually don't mind or expect that, but watch out.

Similarly, interpolation might often best be done like this: transform (e.g. to logarithms) -- interpolate -- back-transform. So, for example, when changes are essentially multiplicative not additive, this would be a good idea.

(Statistically, many people might be queasy about sample size or degrees of freedom when 11/12 of the data for some variables are synthesised using a deterministic rule.)

Here's an extension to all panels:

```
webuse grunfeld, clear
gen month = 7
* general recipe: add 11 observations 
set obs 211 
replace month = _n - 200 in 201/206
replace month = _n - 199 in 207/211
fillin company month year
drop if missing(company, year)
gen mdate = ym(year, month)
format mdate %tm 
mipolate mvalue mdate, gen(mvalue2) pchip by(company) 
scatter mvalue2 mvalue mdate, ms(Oh +) by(company)
```